# Blackboard not importing Blackboard.zip

Tags: r-exams, blackboard

I'm trying to import the Blackboard.zip file created by r/exams but I got the following warning

> ```
> Dec 10, 2020 2:00:36 PM - [FATAL] Fatal: An error has occurred. The error recorded is:
>   The .zip file you provided failed to import. Please try again with a new file.
>   For more information, see the detailed log.
> Dec 10, 2020 2:00:36 PM - [WARNING] Status: The operation import did not complete.
> ```

I thought that it was problem of my R installation, and tried to import the file given in http://www.r-exams.org/assets/posts/2018-04-16-exams2blackboard//blackboard.zip

and even so I get the same error message.

Does anyone knows what is happening? I even try to import a QTI 2.1 file generated by exams package and same error.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Hmmm, strange. Niels (the main author behind `exams2blackboard`) did a couple of improvements in the development version. I'm not sure whether any of the fixes are related to your problem but maybe you can try again after: `install.packages("exams", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`. Re: QTI 2.1. We haven't checked what kind of tweaks in the QTI 2.1 are necessary for Bb, yet, that's still on the to-do list for 2021...

Answer (score 1):

I asked my co-author Niels Smits - the main author behind `exams2blackboard` - to check what is going on. He confirms that the old `blackboard.zip` file shared with our blog post from April 2018 does not work in current versions of Blackboard anymore. Potentially this is caused by a duplication of some files in the `.zip` that we had overlooked in earlier versions of R/exams

However, R/exams version 2.4-0 has fixed several problems with `exams2blackboard` which apparently also solves the problems you are describing. Thus, please update R/exams to a version of at least 2.4-0 and you should be able to avoid the reported issues. After that the output from `exams2blackboard` should work as an input for current Blackboard versions.

Regarding the QTI 2.1 support. The `exams2qti21` function tries to follow the guidance in the official [IMS QTI 2.1 description](https://www.imsglobal.org/question/qtiv2p1/imsqti_infov2p1.html) and has mostly been tested with OpenOLAT. The QTI 2.1 XML files produced by `exams2qti21` do not cooperate with Blackboard, yet, presumably because Blackboard has introduced their own QTI 2.1 "flavor". (Note that Blackboard's QTI 1.2 flavor also deviated quite substantially from a plain QTI 1.2 implementation.) We still have to look into this to check whether we can support Blackboard's QTI 2.1 flavor as well.